# How to give user opportunity to select attribute by checkbox

Tags: views

I use exposed filters in Views to give user opportunity to chose attribute of product. After his checking filtering starts automaticly.
But problem is that format for chosing is drop menu. Is it possible to use checkboxes or radio buttons? It will be more userfriendly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) seems to be module you need:

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single- or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively. Description fields and Select All/None links can be added to exposed filters to make for a better user experience.